# Remove All Files from a Collection in MongoDB

Tags: file, mongodb, collections

I have a collection named, phpDemo in a database named, test in my MongoDB server. The collection, phpDemo contains 8 files.

I want to remove all these 8 files which are in my collection. Since I am a rookie in MongoDB, I take the help of Google to learn about this NoSQL-type database. I searched for a function how to remove all the files that currently in my collection and I found this page, http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/ that told me to execute the db.collection.remove() function.

I executed the function but even after doing so, it did not delete any of the files. I crosschecked by executing the db.collection.count() function and it returned the value, 8.

Can anyone tell me why isn't this function doing its job properly? Replies at the earliest will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you seeing an error message or is nothing happening?

Comment: @ Ray Toal: Thank you very much for replying. I found the solution to the problem myself. I have posted the answer.

Comment: That was a funny mistake :). Great Razor that you find the solution yourself. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got the solution to the problem myself. You have to replace 'collection' in db.collection.remove() with the name of your collection. So in my case, the command that I will need to execute is: db.phpDemo.remove()